# Athena / Presto query with date doesn't work with variable

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Base query without variable works - however while trying to use variable I am running into issue

**Works:**

```sql
myquery = "SELECT * FROM  x where range between '2021-08-08' and '2021-08-09'
```

Attempt 1:

```py
start_date = '2021-08-08'
end_date = '2021-08-09'
        
myquery = "SELECT * FROM  x where range between date '{start_date}' and date '{end_date}'
myquery =  myquery.format(start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date)
        
Error - Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN date and date'
```

Attempt 2:

```py
myquery = "SELECT * FROM  x where range between date ({start_date}) and date ({end_date})
myquery =  myquery.format(start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date)
        
Error- Unexpected parameters (integer) for function date. Expected: date(varchar(x)) , date(timestamp) , date(timestamp with time zone)
```

Attempt 3:

```py
myquery = "SELECT * FROM  x where range between CAST ({start_date} AS DATE) and CAST({end_date} AS DATE)
myquery =  myquery.format(start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date)

Error : Cannot cast integer to date'
```

Attempt 4:

```py
myquery = "SELECT * FROM  x where range between {start_date} and {end_date}
myquery =  myquery.format(start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date)

Error: Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN integer and integer'
```

Any insights into what I need to modify - all SO search around this points to above attempts.

Comment: How do you execute the query?

Comment: its ran from jupyter notebook via boto on athena - as i said i am able to run it if I dont try variable part

Comment: please add the code.

Comment: I suggest you print out the contents of `myquery` after doing the formatting. You'll probably find that the date isn't formatted the way you expect.

Comment: Great suggestion and quite lame of me to not compare actual queries - found the issue

Comment: Query which was getting run in failure case was below : 
SELECT * FROM  x where range between 2021-01-04 and 2021-01-04

Comment: All I had to do was remove date and add ' ' literal                                              
 "SELECT * FROM  x where range between date '{start_date}' and date '{end_date}'

Comment: @JohnRotenstein- thanks for the pointer appreciate it !!

Comment: Have you tried date_format function in Presto? date_format({start_date}, 'yyyy-mm-dd'). Refer to: https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query works because you test if a string is between two strings (`'2021-08-08'` is a string literal), but the other queries declare the interpolated values as dates (`DATE '2021-08-08'` is a date literal).

When you drop the quotes around your interpolated values they look like integer expressions (`2021-08-08` is "2021 minus 8 minus 8"), this causes some of the other errors you get.

You can fix your query either by removing the casts, or adding another cast to make the `range` value a date:

```
myquery = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE range BETWEEN '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
```

or

```
myquery = "SELECT * FROM x WHERE CAST(range AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE '{start_date}' and DATE '{end_date}'
```

Both will work since ISO 8601 dates sort the same whether compared as dates or strings.